# In spark how can I agg a column into a frequency map with the unique values in that column and their frequency

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have records that contain ip and port columns in an RDD.

```
#Expected input

Record 1
--------------
ip     |  1.1.1.1.1
port   |  80

Record 2
--------------
ip     |  1.1.1.1.1
port   |  43

Record 3
--------------
ip     |  1.1.1.1.1
port   |  43
```

My goal is to run an aggregation and build out a map where the keys are the unique ports and the value in the map is their frequency in the records/columns

```
#Expected Output

Record 1
-------------
ip     |  1.1.1.1
ports  |  [80 -> 1, 43 -> 2]
```

I was hoping to have the code work in one action(The code below does not work just as an example):

```
raw_df.groupBy('ip').agg(
  f.map_from_entries(f.collect_list(f.col("port"), count)).alias('ports')
)
```

I just haven't been able to find a way in one step to get a frequence map. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one more group by before aggregating into a map:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.groupBy(
    'ip', 'port'
).agg(
    F.count('*').alias('count_port')
).groupBy(
    'ip'
).agg(
    F.map_from_entries(F.collect_list(F.struct('port', 'count_port'))).alias('ports')
)

result.show()
+---------+------------------+
|       ip|             ports|
+---------+------------------+
|1.1.1.1.1|[80 -> 1, 43 -> 2]|
+---------+------------------+
```